# Run Windows Phone Emulator on 32-bit version of Windows

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I have the 32-bit version of Windows 10.  I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, but I am unable to find the emulator for Windows Phone.

How can I test my application?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone SDK uses Hyper-V, which requires a 64-bit platform for the host.

See below for an excerpt.  Note the requirements listed under **Operating System**.

> ## System requirements for the emulator for Windows Phone 8
>
> Your computer must meet the following requirements:
>
> ### BIOS
>
> In the BIOS, the following features must be supported:
>
> - Hardware-assisted virtualization.
> - Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
> - Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP).
>
> ### RAM
>
> - 4 GB or more.
>
> ### Operating system
>
> - Windows 8
> - **64-bit**
> - Pro edition or higher

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx)

## Notice Regarding Universal Apps (`UWP`)

Universal Apps targeting Windows 10 can be created and tested on a 32-bit (`x86`) platform, but you will be unable to build and test applications for 64-bit (`x64`) and `ARM` platforms.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt244352.aspx)

Comment: thank your for your answer..is there any other i can test windows app..

POST: I have windows phone running os 7.10
and 
my system requirement 
windows 10 PRO N
4gb Ram
Visualization enabled
Hyper V Enabled
is there any way i can test my app like third party emulator